# How to make images the same size with CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I want my 3 images to be the same size, but width/height styles aren't helping, because when I set the same size for all images, all 3 images keep their aspect ratio and they look horrible.

What I got:
[image: What i got]

What  want to get:
[image: What i want to get]

```css
.social {
  display: flex;
}

.items_soc {
  height: auto;
  width: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150" />
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/aaa" />
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" />
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear. Do your images, in their initial state, have the same height/width ratio or not? and if not, are you looking to distort this ratio?

Comment: if there is a possibility to avoid distorting would be good

Comment: You can't avoid to get a distortion when you want to fit a rectangle into a square.  this is pure logic !

Comment: aren't there a way like object-fit: cover ? because it will be non flex, and it will be needed to be resized if making adaptive page

Comment: Why didn't you respond to my first comment? you just have to answer yes or no.

Comment: @MisterJojo, yes, yes and yes

Comment: So if they have the same ratio, you don't need to use any `object-fit` value in your css

Comment: You need to explore [SO Guidelines (help section)](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @SteveJames, your solution is the best) Ty for help

Comment: The two images you show here doesn't have the same W/H ratio (the 1->1.143, the 2->1.271)

Comment: There is nothing sarcastic in the comments, rather you should thank me for rewriting your CSS code image to respect SO and markDown writing standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object fit works the best when you have a constant aspect ratio.
Change the code to

```css
.social {
  display: flex;
}

.items_soc {
  height: 50px;  /* Set the desired height */
  width: 50px;  /* Set the desired width */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%); */
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150" />
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/aaa" />
  <img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" />
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't change the size of my images, everything is the same(

Comment: It's usually best to _not_ set the width, which will distort the image. Just set height.

Answer (score 0):

I see what is your problem and if you want them be the same height and width it will be dependent if you want it vertical or horizonal order for the method I will stating.

For this you must enclose each image within the `<div>` element. Once you have done that you can use CSS to declare the specifics for its height and width. You can use the style attribute within the div opening tag. `style = "width : 100px; height: 100px;"` . It follows the same rules.

Then you can insert your images with its sources. Their aspect ratio should stay the same and fit within the div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style = "width: 1000px; height: 50px;">
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/aaa" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is more for list and rosters but you can also just try to have a height value and have the width as auto instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/aaa" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
<img class="items_soc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" style = "height: 50px; width: auto;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Same result, different use case.